# Error al abrir ventana modal con botones de una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Tengo datos de unos registros que muestro en una vista con blade, estos registros están dentro de un `foreach` y cada registro aparece en una fila, a la derecha de la tabla están los botones de ver, editar y borrar. La cuestión es la siguiente el botón de borrar le he asociado una ventana modal, el problema es que en el primer botón la modal abre de maravilla, a partir del segundo boton no abre la modal.

código del botón eliminar

```
    @foreach($una as $unas)
// otros datos en la tabla
         <button  id="delete_button" class="circular basic ui icon button" >
              <i class="icon delete" title="Eliminar usuario"></i>
         </button>
    @endforeach
```

EL query que debe desplegar esto :

```
$('#delete_button').click(function(){
            $('.ui.basic.modal').modal('show');
        });
```

Tal cual como esta en la documentación de semantic UI.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resumiendo : en la primera X funciona correcto al darle a las siguientes no funciona.

Comment: estas usando un id para esa funcion (#delete-button), lo que podrias hacer es llamar la funcion con onlcick, algo asi:
<button onclick="myFunction()">X</button>

Comment: Vale Eddy lo revisaré ... muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claramente el error es que utilizas un `id`(que debe de ser único) en varias filas, el id al ser único solo funciona con el primero que encuentro el DOM.

Para solucionar tu problema puedes utilizar `class`, que si te funcionara en tu caso

Ej:

```js
$('.delete_button').click(function(){
             el_texto_primera_columna=$(this).parent("td").parent("tr").children("td nth:child(1)").html();
            console.log("un texto:"+el_texto_primera_columna);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Nro
        </th>
        <th>botones
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td> uno
        </td>
        <td>
        <button type="button" class="circular basic ui icon button delete_button" >
              <i class="icon delete" title="Eliminar usuario"></i>
         </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> dos
        </td>
        <td>
        <button type="button" class="circular basic ui icon button delete_button" >
              <i class="icon delete" title="Eliminar usuario"></i>
         </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> tres
        </td>
        <td>
        <button type="button" class="circular basic ui icon button delete_button" >
              <i class="icon delete" title="Eliminar usuario"></i>
         </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> cuatro
        </td>
        <td>
        <button type="button" class="circular basic ui icon button delete_button" >
              <i class="icon delete" title="Eliminar usuario"></i>
         </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias Shassain la verdad no lo habia pensado. Gracias  voy a probarlo

Comment: Efectivamente , lo he solucionado. Muchas gracias